# Powershell UIAutomation - how to identify methods supported by an object?

Tags: powershell, ui-automation

I'm just learning a bit of UIA with PoSH. So far so good, albeit somewhat basic.... I have worked out the following:

```
$np = get-uiawindow -class 'notepad' -name '*'
$npedit = $np | Get-UiaDocument
#  $npedit | send-keys "abc"
$npedit | Set-UiaControlText "def"
$currtext = $npedit | Get-UiaDocumentRangeText
```

So then the next obvious stage was to automate driving ie, or chrome...

```
$ie = Get-UiaWindow -class 'ieframe' -name 'environment agenc*'
$addbar = $ie | Get-UiaPane -automationid '40966' -class "rebarwindow32"
$addbar | Set-UiaControlText "news.bbc.co.uk"
```

But it seems objects of class `rebarwindow32` do not support "`Set-UiaControlText`".

Similarly, in my earlier experimenting, I also tried automating the windows calculator. Clicking buttons etc is easy enough, but trying to read the results of any calculation proved more challenging - the UIAutomationSpy showed it as a UiaText object of class "`Static`".

So all this is aimed at asking a fairly simple question - how can I identify what methods are supported by any one object - I'm not asking just HOW to get the current value in the calculator results, or HOW to set the IE browser address bar... but HOW to FIND OUT for myself, what methods any one object I have identified supports.

Everything I've googled so far has shown specific examples of "How to do this or that" (eg select a menu, set some text) - but all very specific.

Based on comments from mike z below, I've now tried GetSupportedPatterns, which (based on a bit of googling on GetSupportedPatterns, is exactly what I need!).

However, if (based on my sample code above) I do `$np.GetSupportedPatterns()` I get:

```
Cached                                  Current 
------                                  -------
UIAutomation.UiaWindowPattern+Window... UIAutomation.UiaWindowPattern+Window...
UIAutomation.UiaTransformPattern+Tra... UIAutomation.UiaTransformPattern+Tra...
```

Which doesn't seem to tell me very much - and I cannot widen my window? Also, why only the cached operations, rather than the full list?

Thanks

Steve

Comment: Have you tried `Get-Member`? Just pipe an object to that cmdlet and it will show you the methods.

Comment: Thanks @entbark - that's certainly helped out (as you can probably tell, Im rediscovering my PoSH skills!)... But I think what I also need is to find out what UIA commands are valid for any given object - for example, in the case of a button, I can use invoke-uiabuttonclick - but what else?! How do I find out all the UIA "commands" for any given object?  (Forgive me if my terminology isn't 100% "correct") ... Many thanks

Comment: If you have an AutomationElement, call GetSupportedPatterns to find the operations supported by the element.

Comment: Hi @mike - thanks for that. Doing a bit of googling on GetSupportedPatterns, I *think* this is exactly what I need. I've now edited my OP to reflect issues with using GetSupportedPatterns (have done this so as to be able to format the output correctly!)... Can you advise further? Many thanks!

Comment: @SteveHall It looks like the library you are using is doing some kind of wrapping of the elements so I don't really know how to use it but I can guess based on what I know about the underlying API. It seems to mimic the existing methods, because it has GetSupportedPatterns, however it is doing something different. It is returning pattern implementation objects rather than pattern descriptors. Normally you get back a descriptor that tells you the pattern name and id. Then you have to call GetCurrentPattern to get the actual implementation. It seems to be doing those in one step for you.

Comment: Hi @mike - sorry to be a pain, but I've just returned to looking at this after a few days of being diverted to other things. If I define my `$np` object as above, and then do `$np | get-member`, then I get the list of members as you might expect, INCLUDING `GetSupportedPatterns`. However, if I then type `$np.Get` and hit <TAB> for command completion, nothing happens. If I manually type `$np.GetSupportedPatterns()` I get `Method invocation failed because [System.Object[]] doesn't contain a method named 'GetSupportedPatterns'.`

What am I now getting wrong?!?

Thanks again